# ClassCastException thrown even though there is no cast

Tags: java, mongodb, classcastexception, objectid

I've got a `HashMap<ObjectId, Integer>` in which I want to add a new entry.
`ObjectId` is a `BSON` class which comes with the `MongoDB-Driver` in my case.

```
 1   @Expose private Map<ObjectId, Integer> usedPaths;
 2   
 3   public Project()
 4   {
 5      this.usedPaths = new HashMap<>();
 6   }
 7
 8   public void usePath(ObjectId someId, int pathId)
 9   {
10      this.usedPaths.put(someId, pathId);
11   }
12
13   public void debug()
14   {
15      usePath(new ObjectId("5bfd98a2c06178796e66c204"), 1);
16   }
```

When I call the debug method, a `ClassCastException` is thrown:

```
    SCHWERWIEGEND: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey Web Application] in context with path [/KnowledgerServer] threw exception [java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.bson.BasicBSONObject.put(BasicBSONObject.java:36)
    at de.knowledger.model.Project.usePath(Project.java:10)
    at de.knowledger.model.Project.debug(Project.java:15)
```

As far as I know and see I don't even try to cast an ObjectId to String, furthermore I'm never accessing the `BasicBSONObject` class in my code, `ObjectId` doesn't extend it either.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How is the `Project` deserialized? I see the `@Expose`-Annotation. Have you tried putting a breakpoint in `usePath`? It seems it isn't a `HashMap`, but a `BasicBSONObject` at runtime.

Comment: In that exception trace, `usedPath` is NOT a `HashMap`. It is a `BasicBSONObject`. Are you sure you have the correct source code?

Comment: What does `@Expose` do? It looks like someone is setting `usedPath` to something unexpected. A `BasicBSONObject` is a `Map`, so this assignment will work, but it is not a `Map<ObjectId,Integer>`, it is more of a `Map<String, Object>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to save and load a HashMap to/from MongoDB, its Java driver handles any passed Map as DBObject.

Thank you for your Tips!

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in the piece of code you have provided, as far as I can see. The exception makes it clear that the class is part of a servlet. The issue could be in what is happening before and after you call the `usePath(...)` method.